# change my home in android if my application is running!

Tags: java, c++, android, c

I want to change my home in android device my requirements are like following
whenever I run my application my that time on pressing home key should be disabled
so that time on pressing home key should do nothing.
but if I close that application my home should be the previous one that is launcher

So it is possible on basis of running application my home get set
I use to change in manifest.xml file and disabling the package `com.android.launcher` but it won't satisfy me.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not an Android user, but wouldn't this be really, really evil?

Comment: Retagged with the `android` tag, I think you'll have more luck getting an answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short... no, you cannot do this.

There are some things you can do as workarounds that would themselves be hacky at best and basically not deliver the functionality you want. Like making your application be home replacement (launcher) itself then applying the desired functionality but even in that scenario it wouldn't do what you described you want done because you wouldn't really ever get back to the previous user defined home app (launcher) and there would be system dialogs the user would need to traverse to set your app as the home replacement (launcher).

Just so it is super clear though, you **cannot override the functionality of the home button** without the user confirming the action.